# Running sbt commands in windows batch file

Tags: scala, batch-file, sbt

I have a program that runs with scala's sbt tool. Is it possible to launch this program with a batch file? I tried to just have something like:

```
sbt
run
```

in a batch file but that didn't work. It just launched the sbt but didn't run the program. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sbt` accepts command line arguments.

Try

```
sbt run
```

(in a single line).

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe it was that easy

Comment: @zamsler, usually is when you read the help and documentation for a program.  Could have gotten that answer by reading the website documentation for SBT.

Comment: @Squashman Would a single `\n`-line break count as "trivial typo"? Then one could close / delete it.